# Processing elements after filter has removed all elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the problem where I filter some elements of the stream and filter can remove some or all elements. How do I handle situation when no elements are left after filtering?

I tried to check if any elements are left using `Optional<T>`, which was a logical thing to do, but even here I get a `NullPointerException`. Here is an example:

```
Optional<T> elem = details.stream()
                .filter(T::test)
                .findFirst(); //<=============== NPE

if(elem.isPreset){...}
```

How can this be handeled?

Comment: You should eliminate all the `null`. For eg: `filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Comment: You don’t get an NPE when there are no elements. You’ll get an empty `Optional`. That’s what `Optional` is for. You get an NPE when there *is* an element, but the element is `null`. Assuming that `T::test` refers to an instance method, this is impossible.

Comment: @Holger it's impossible at that location. But OP probably gets the NPE in the filter() call.

Comment: @Holger you are correct. possibly OP might have missed some map operations after filter. Or can the `T::test` be a static method?

Comment: @Axel right, the possibility that the exception happens at a different place exists.

Comment: NPE was thrown on T::test. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Holger said, the NPE cannot possibly come from the call to `findFirst()` unless a `null` element is present. To make it short: either filter out `null` elements before applying your filter method or make sure it's a static method and returns `false` for `null` elements.

In any case, this should work:

```
Optional<T> elem = details.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(T::test)
                .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Possible Cause

The following are the possibilities for the exception

1. The filtered data might contain `null`

```java
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        records.add(null);
        Optional<String> opt = records.stream().filter(str -> str == null || str.length() > 5).findFirst();
```

2. Please check whether T::test allows `null` value, if so, please fix it
3. Even if the `null` value can come in input and other filters, please add the `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before invoking `findFirst`

### Suggestion

Try using non null filter

```java
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        records.add(null);
        Optional<String> opt = records.stream().filter(str -> str == null || str.length() > 5).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst();
```

Comment: It’s inconsistent to use a filter like `str -> str == null || str.length() > 5`, explicitly allowing `null`, to add another `filter` sorting out the `null` elements afterwards. You can use `.filter(str -> str != null && str.length() > 5)` in the first place. Or you change the order: `.filter(Objects::nonNull) .filter(str -> str.length() > 5)`

Comment: @Holger, in the first section, `Possible Cause`, i was trying to reproduce the scenario with null passing through filter. My intention was to suggest about possible bugs that an escape filter. In the second part, `Suggestion` was proposing a solution incase of null values coming from previous filter or possible a map transformation. Please correct if this approach of answering is incorrect?

Comment: Right, and the solution should be not to let `null` pass. Regardless of what the OP’s predicate does, placing `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before it will do.

Comment: `.filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(T::test)` or the question poster will still think that NPE is coming from `findFirst`. Chaining makes it a little tricky to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, Still the `NPE` could from `findFirst` if the `T::test` static method allows `null`

Comment: I don't think this needs a discussion right now until we get feedback. Everything discussed here was purely based on assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

from what I'm seeing, your code seems fine. Optional should be able to store the null value without throwing an exception.

then the next line of code:

```
if(elem.isPreset){
/// your logic on elem goes here
}
```

should prevent the code from NPE cause if `elem` is null that condition should be false.

the NPE is likely coming from this line:

```
Optional<T> elem = details.stream()
                .filter(T::test)//<=============== NPE
                .findFirst();
```

so I recommend adding this:

```
Optional<T> elem = details.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)//<== this removes null elems
                .filter(T::test)
                .findFirst();
```